# CE1 not going low for pigpio.spi_open() with flags

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, spi, python-3, pigpio

I'm attempting to modify joan's test script (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44320/42126) for an RPi SPI master to communicate with an Atmega328P slave. I cannot change which GPIO pins I have configured due to hardware constraints in my project.

I need to use CE1(BCM7) and auxiliary SPI (BCM[19:21])

My test script is below:

```
pi = pigpio.pi()
channel = 1             # use CE1
flags = 0b100000000;  # use auxiliary SPI
h = pi.spi_open(channel, baud)
#h = pi.spi_open(channel, baud, flags)

n = 0
while True:
    n += 1
    pi.spi_xfer(h, "Message {}\n".format(n))
    time.sleep(1)

pi.spi_close(h)
pi.stop()
```

I'm using an analog discovery unit as a logic analyzer, connected as follows:

```
 DIO0 CE1 (BCM7(
 DIO1 SCK0 (BCM11)
 DIO2 MOSI0 (BCM10)
 DIO3 MISO0 (BCM9)
 DIO4 SCK1 (BCM21)
 DIO5 MOSI1 (BCM20)
 DIO6 MISO1 (BCM19)
 DIO7 CE2 (BCM16)
```

If I use the flag to select auxiliary spi, I get clock and data, but SS doesn't go low.

[image: Auxiliary SPI, CE1]

If I don't use a flag and monitor primary SPI with CE1, I get a good connection
[image]

If I use channel 2 (the one normally associated with auxilary spi), I get data as well as CS2 low (MISO is not connected to the slave for this sample)
[image]

It appears that channel 1 is not being brought low, but the documentation (http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#spi_open) allows using channel 1 with auxiliary SPI. I don't see any flags that would conflict with this configuration ...
am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a misunderstanding.  The usage of GPIO by the main and auxiliary SPI devices is as follows.

```
         MISO MOSI SCLK CE0 CE1 CE2
Main SPI  9   10   11    8   7   -
Aux SPI  19   20   21   18  17  16
```

If you want to use the auxiliary SPI with a non-standard chip select you will have to toggle the GPIO yourself.

This is straightforward.  Set the selected GPIO low before each transfer and set it high afterwards.

E.g.

```py
pi.write(7, 0)
(count, rx_data) = pi.spi_xfer(h, [1, 128, 0])
pi.write(7, 1)
```